# Php download of *.zip or *.rar file are corrupted

Tags: php, http, download, zip

I'm trying a download of a protected zip, rar file. After trying hundreds of different headers and combinations, I'm lost. I cann download images, pdf but zip and rar are corrupted.

Where is the problem?

[image]

**Code**

```
$url = url_for('/staff/photos/error.php');
$error = $url;

//$filepath = 'C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\public\files\3d_models';
$url2 = PROJECT_PATH.DS.'public'.DS.'files'.DS.'3d_models';
$filepath = $url2;

$filename = null;

if (isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file']) {
    $filename = $_GET['file'];
} else {
    header("Location: $error");
    exit;
}

if ($filename) {

    $abs_path = $filepath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
    if (file_exists($abs_path) && is_readable($abs_path)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Type: application/rar");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header('Content-length: ' . filesize($abs_path));
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
        readfile($abs_path);
    } else {
        header("Location: $error");
    }
}
```

Comment: `header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Type: application/rar");` ...you can't send _both_ those headers at once. Pick one depending on the file type. Not sure if that's your entire problem but it's unlikely to help.

Comment: @ ADyson I removed the (application/rar) rar, and it's the same

Comment: ok well it's a start. Sanity check: have you verified that the file(s) in question are definitely valid to begin with? i.e. can you open them successfully from their original location directly without involving your PHP script?

Comment: Second sanity check, have you verified that `$abs_path` points to a valid location on the server's disk and that the webserver's account has permission to read from it?

Comment: @ ADyson rest api http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/photo_gallery/public/staff/rest_api/get_id.php?id=41

Comment: @ ADyson valid location 'yes'

Comment: @Syruiusz er...these files are publicly available. You don't need a PHP script to serve them. Just add hyperlinks to the files into your HTML page.

Comment: @ADyson api is for one customer but http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/photo_gallery/public/show.php?id=39 - for everyone. And what about security?

Comment: I don't know what your security requirements are. If you don't want these files to be accessible to everyone then don't put them in a public folder on your website. And then of course you _would_ need a PHP script to serve them, and the PHP script would need to check the user's credentials before returning the data. I was only making the observation that, as your site is currently designed, there would be no need for the PHP. But if that's not your real requirement then you first need to change your site's folder structure.

Comment: @ADyson The download script must block any attempt to explore the file system.

Comment: @ADyson  I think something is wrong is with header's, encoding....

Comment: The download script can't stop the user going to another URL entirely in their browser. Like I said if you want to restrict access to the files then you must 1) move your files outside the public folder of your site, to somewhere else on your server's disk, and then 2) write some PHP code in the download script to check whether the person making the request is authorised to view that file before retrieving it. Since I don't know the rules for that, I can't advise you how to do it exactly.

Comment: Once you've got that right, then you can move onto the problems with the actual downloading.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your help, if I manage to do something today I will let you know.

Comment: ADyson See my solution.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**
I added:

```
ob_start();

if ($filename) {
$abs_path = $filepath . DS . $filename;
if (file_exists($abs_path) && is_readable($abs_path)) {

        header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-length: ' . filesize($abs_path));
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
        header('Content-transfer-encoding: binary');  

        while (ob_get_level()) {
        ob_end_clean();
        }
        readfile($abs_path);     

    } else {
        header("Location: $error");
    }
}
```